# WebP Conversion Tools optional for webp optimized image extension?

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

1.Are WebP Conversion Tools like GD, CWEBP OR Imagick needed if I buy the Web Optimized Images Extension, or these tools are optional?

2.In what format I need to continue upload the new images if I purchase an extension: JPG/PNG?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Are WebP Conversion Tools like GD, CWEBP OR Imagick needed if I buy the Web Optimized Images Extension, or these tools are optional?

**Answer - That is depends on module which you are going to purchased, but most of tools used GD library or Imagick**

2.In what format I need to continue upload the new images if I purchase an extension: JPG/PNG?

**Answer - If you have option of upload svg, that is too much good. If not then use jpg, png image is much heavier then jpg.**

Comment: So If I purchase this extention for Magento ver. 2.3.0 I don't need to upload GD library or Imagick tool, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you are referring to our [WebP Optimized Images for Magento 2 extension](https://www.jajuma.de/en/jajuma-develop/extensions/webp-optimized-images-extension-for-magento-2)

> Are WebP Conversion Tools like GD, CWEBP OR Imagick needed if I buy
>   the Web Optimized Images Extension, or these tools are optional?

Yes, for local conversion of image files from e. g. JPG/PNG to WebP, there is always a conversion tool needed on your server.

Our extension was designed to be as easy to use and as flexible as possible.
By supporting not just one, but all three mentioned conversion tools (GD, CWEBP OR Imagick), it should be no big deal to get at least one of these tools up and running correctly with support for .webp images.
In fact, most sites have a software stack on their server that allows them to use the extension right away, just some need their server guys to install or update one of the tools to be ready.
In our [WebP Images FAQ](https://www.jajuma.de/en/jajuma-develop/extensions/webp-optimized-images-extension-for-magento-2/webp-images-faq) we explain how to check availability of GD / CWEBP / Imagick on a server from command line.
With the extension installed, it is also possible to check conversion setup conveniently from backend using the included conversion test tool.

> 2.In what format I need to continue upload the new images if I purchase an extension: JPG/PNG?

It does not matter, you can upload new images as JPG or PNG.
Both, existing as well as newly uploaded JPG/PNG images will be converted automatically by our extension.